# NSCoding to CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, nscoding

I have a custom class with which i made an (swift-y) struct NSCodable. Now I want to convert that into a CKRecord in order to use CloudKit. Even though I set 'key value'-pairs when encoding my struct, it is in my understanding that the struct is converted into NSData and that you can't convert it to a Dictionary (or another key-value object). So I get the feeling that this is not the way to go.

Is there a way to make this conversion directly? Or with a step in-between (for instance converting the Data into a [String: String]- dictionary)?

Comment: You can store the `NSData` in a CKRecord.

Comment: But that would result in a data-blob inside a CKRecord. I would like to have a convenient way of converting it.

Answer (score 0):

NSCoding is only for going from/to the same class. Instead, write a toServerDictionary method on your custom class, including only the properties you want to send to CloudKit, and then use the result to call [setValuesForKeys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1417515-setvaluesforkeys) on a CKRecord.

You'll likely find there are properties that need to be specific types, in which case its better to make your method toServerRecord and create a CKRecord and return it. You can also have a updateWithServerRecord to set anything you receive back.